# How to get the array name from a variable

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

How to get the array name from the below  ?

Getting the name of the array from config :

```
jobcfgUniqName=`echo ${config_data} | awk -F "#" '{print $3}'`
```

Creating an array of it :

```
for ((xx = 0; xx <= ${#joblognameSearch[@]}; xx++))
do
    print $joblognameSearch[$xx]
    eval ($jobcfgUniqName)[$xx]=`grep -B 3 -i  error  $joblogPath/$joblognameSearch[$xx]`
    print jobcfgUniqName : ${jobcfgUniqName}
done
```

This line I tried changing many ways but did not work :

```
eval ($jobcfgUniqName)[$xx]
```

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to do. There are ways to do this but eval is dangerous.

Comment: I am trying to get the array name from a configuration file and use it to store the error from the logs . I will be reading a lot of different logs so dont want to fetch everything in the same array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `declare` bulletin of BASH to replace your eval by this:

```
declare arr_"$jobcfgUniqName"[$xx]=`grep -B 3 -i error $joblogPath/$joblognameSearch[$xx]`
```

Now you will have dynamic array create with prefix `arr_` and some variable name `$jobcfgUniqName`.

#### TESTING:

```
# set the array
s='abc'
declare arr_"$s"[0]='foo'
declare arr_"$s"[1]='bar'

# retrieve the values
v1=arr_"$s"[0]
v2=arr_"$s"[1]

echo "${!v1}"
foo
echo "${!v2}"
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `echo`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
A="abcd dcba"
B=A
C='eval "echo \$$B"'
eval "$C"

$ bash 1.sh
abcd dcba
```